# Is this a conditional promise?

Tags: oaths, kaffarah, pornography

Assalamualaikum may Allah SWT bless you for helping me out because I am in great confusion. Once when I was being very guilty about my actions ( I was addicted to some sort of p***) I said to Allah that please don't let anyone see the phone's history (it was a family phone ) and I said I will never repeat this action again please don't let anybody get to know about it I promise I will never do that again. So does this statement make it a conditional vow or promise? Does it mean if Allah will listen my dua then I cannot return to the same sin again? meaning will I be breaking a promise or vow?

Answer (score 0):

From the nature of this scenario, it probably is a promise / agreement between you and Allah. *However*, if Allah decides that leaking this information is for your best, then he will do it. Only Allah knows best.

**P.S.:** You should also ask an Imam or another scholar about this as well, I am not that knowledgeable. And also, make dua and ask for forgiveness from this sin.